# How to display shipping method in cart page of opecart

Tags: opencart

Anyone tell me how to diplay shipping method in cart page of opecart when i click on checkout?

```
PRODUCT                 PRODUCT TITLE           UNIT PRICE  TOTAL
Chandramrit Ras         CHANDRAMRIT RAS         Rs. 120     Rs. 120
Agnikumar Ras           AGNIKUMAR RAS           Rs. 90      Rs. 90
Arvindasav              ARVINDASAV              Rs. 55      Rs. 55
Vindhya Nimbadi Capsule VINDHYA NIMBADI CAPSULE Rs. 300     Rs. 3,000
Sub-Total:  Rs. 3,265
Total:      Rs. 3,265
```

here display only total but I want to add here shipping method

Comment: Shipping method is available only in the checkout process, it is not possible to display it in cart overview. What is exactly that you want to achieve? In the checkout after the payment and shipping options are selected the last step before the order is created is again a summary of ordered products with additional information about sub-total, total and **shipping** costs (or additional taxes). Why do you need this in cart overview?

Comment: My client wants shipping rate in cart page

Comment: As explained above, that is not possible in default installation. If Your client has only one shipping method, then it could be possible by little modification of cart page controller but if the customer has the possibility to choose one option from more shipping possibilities then **this is not possible on cart page**. Clients often want stupid things. Usually I overcharge for stupid things (they just want but do not really need and they are meaningless) so that clients say: *Ooh, that much? OK, let's skip that feature for now.*